# Installing proftpd - dependency issues (libcrypto.so and libssl.so.10)

Tags: centos, openssl, ftp

I'm trying to install proftpd (for usage with zpanel if that's relevant), but I can't get passed these dependencies issues. I've tried to add a bunch of different packages/repos for yum, but it still produces the exact same error. At first I thought this was an issue with the epel package and system architecture, but the package ends with noarch which means no architecture (?). Anyway, I've been adding and removing packages, and now I just added this: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

Same error. Tried to update openssl, even reinstall it - but still it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what I can do? I've really done my fair share of Googling without any luck.

Iam on CentOS 6.4 final if that's relevant. Here's what happens when I run yum install proftpd:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                         |  25 kB     00:00     
 * base: n1plmirror01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 * epel: mirror.muntinternet.net
 * extras: n1plmirror01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
 * updates: n1plmirror01.shr.prod.ams1.secureserver.net
base                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                | 3.4 kB     00:00     
kbs-CentOS-Extras                                                                                     | 1.9 kB     00:00     
kbs-CentOS-Testing                                                                                    | 1.9 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                               | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package proftpd.x86_64 0:1.3.3g-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libGeoIP.so.1()(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package GeoIP.x86_64 0:1.4.8-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package proftpd.x86_64 0:1.3.3g-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: proftpd-1.3.3g-4.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: `yum` appears to be in an unclean state, run `yum-complete-transaction` to let it resolve pending transactions - they might include your dependency packages.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this but it didn't work :(
I've figured it out though, but I cannot post answer yet due to low reputation (I thought that followed from Stackoverflow, but it didn't). Will post answer later for others!


FIXED IT: http://pastebin.com/XWWvPHfr

Comment: If you're on StackOverflow with enough points you can link accounts and you'll get 100 points here. Or you could pastebin the answer for me to supply 8-)

Comment: I'll link my accounts and answer it myself then! Thanks!

Comment: I guess I need to wait. I'll post the solution later today. Again; thanks for your quick reply and help!

Comment: `There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.` This is a SERIOUS ERROR and should be fixed before attempting to install any other packages. Otherwise your system may eventually become unrecoverable. In additon, GoDaddy is probably causing this problem that you posted about. See the duplicate question for details.